# Tomcat LDAP Roles : No Role Found

Tags: apache, ldap, tomcat7, jndi, web.xml

I am erroring whilst authenticating Domain User account (user01) using JNDI to LDAP. Although not technically an error, it reads

```
 Username user01 does NOT have role Domain Users
```

I thought and its my understanding an AD group (where the user logging into the application exists) can be mapped to the role name within the web.xml code to allow a user to log into the application.

My current JNDI Realm configuration is as followings:

../tomcat7/conf/server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
debug="99"
connectionURL="ldap://example.com:389"
authentication="simple"
referrals="follow"
connectionName="cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"
connectionPassword="xxxxxxxxxx"
userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
userBase="dc=example,dc=com"
userSubtree="true"
userRoleName="memberOf"
roleSearch="(member={0})"
roleName="cn"
roleSubtree="true"
roleBase="dc=example,dc=com" />
```

../tomcat7/webapps/appdir/WEB-INF/web.xml (here I have attempted to specify the AD Domain 'Users group' under the 'role-name' constraint):

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Domain User Access</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Domain Users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <description>Webapp Admins</description>
    <role-name>Domain Admins</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <description>Webapp Users</description>
    <role-name>Domain Users</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Entire Application</realm-name>
</login-config>
</web-app>
```

../tomcat7/logs/catalina.out (tailed last 10 lines it captures the cause - i think - to the issue but I don't know how to rectify this)

```
Oct 10, 2018 4:53:55 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase 
register
FINE: Authenticated 'leeb' with type 'BASIC'
Oct 10, 2018 4:53:55 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase 
invoke
FINE:  Calling accessControl()
Oct 10, 2018 4:53:55 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase 
hasResourcePermission
FINE:   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[user01(CN=Domain 
Admins,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com,Domain Admins,)]
Oct 10, 2018 4:53:55 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase hasRole
FINE: Username user01 does NOT have role Domain Users
Oct 10, 2018 4:53:55 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase 
hasResourcePermission
FINE: No role found:  Domain Users
Oct 10, 2018 4:53:55 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase 
invoke
FINE:  Failed accessControl() test
```

Can anyone offer any advice or spot a glaring error? I need another pair of eyes to see where this configuration is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Domain users is a built in function that reports all users in the domain as belonging to this group ... except not when the query is made through LDAP. If you look at the object with an LDAP browser, it does not have a 'member' attribute. Similarly, an LDAP query for "(&(memberOf=CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=ccTLD))" returns no users.

In my domain, I created an "All Users" group that is added as part of the new user creation process -- not bad when user creation is algorithmic, but certainly less than ideal for manual provisioning. We use this real group for LDAP applications that want all users to have some base level of access.

Where having a traditional group will all accounts populated as members is not possible, you can use ADAM to front AD & create a proxy object that, for example, encompasses users where (&(primaryGroupID=513)) {users whose primary group is Domain Users} or (&(objectCategory=person)). I'm not sure if you can do the same thing in AD LDS (which replaced ADAM), though, as I started using the real AD group a few years ago.